# Getting the application icon for Installed Shortcut in Android

Tags: android

I am creating shortcuts of the installed application from my device. I want to get the launcher icons of all applications in my app. But since I don't know the code to get it, I'm using this one for the mean time (*it's the icon of the current app that I'm developing*):

```
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(context, R.drawable.ic_launcher));
```

May you please help me to get the launcher icon of the installed application from the device?

Here's my code for installing shortcut.

```
 ActivityInfo ai = res.get(app_id).activityInfo;

 Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
 shortcutIntent.setClassName(ai.packageName, ai.name);
 shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, appName);
 intent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(context, R.drawable.ic_launcher));
 intent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");      
 context.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Till Now, an app cannot force itself onto the home screen. It basically get added to the app list that the launcher app maintains, generally the home screen is generally under user control. Giving apps the ability to clutter up the home screen would be an open invitation for abuse.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the icons of all the applications on your device and display them as girdview follow the below code. Hope that helps.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

GridView mGrid;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    loadApps();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.myGrid);
    mGrid.setAdapter(new AppsAdapter());
}

private List<ResolveInfo> mApps;

private void loadApps() {
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    mApps = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
}

public class AppsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public AppsAdapter() {
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        CheckableLayout l;
        ImageView i;

        if (convertView == null) {
            i = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
            i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            i.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(50, 50));
            l = new CheckableLayout(MainActivity.this);
            l.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(GridView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    GridView.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            l.addView(i);
        } else {
            l = (CheckableLayout) convertView;
            i = (ImageView) l.getChildAt(0);
        }

        ResolveInfo info = mApps.get(position);
        i.setImageDrawable(info.activityInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager()));

        return l;
    }


    public final int getCount() {
        return mApps.size();
    }

    public final Object getItem(int position) {
        return mApps.get(position);
    }

    public final long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}

public class CheckableLayout extends FrameLayout implements Checkable {
    private boolean mChecked;

    public CheckableLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        mChecked = checked;
//            setBackgroundDrawable(checked ?
//                    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blue)
//                    : null);
            setBackground(checked ?
                    getResources().getDrawable(R.color.black)
                    : null);


    }

    public boolean isChecked() {
        return mChecked;
    }

    public void toggle() {
        setChecked(!mChecked);
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/myGrid"
  android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"

    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="60dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"

    android:gravity="center" />
```

Comment: Getting error in i.addView(i). It says, The method addView(ImageView) is undefined for the type ImageView.

Comment: And also at the line i = (ImageView) i.getChildAt(0), it says, The method getChildAt(int) is undefined for the type ImageView

Comment: @androidBoomer: My bad, sorry!! I've updated the code in my answer.

Comment: It's working!!! However, what I want to happen in my custom launcher app is that, in my admin activity, when I selected an application, that will be the time that it will create a shortcut icon for the selected app in the main activity.